# Symbolic link and filezilla over sftp

Tags: debian, sftp, symbolic-link, ftp

I'm pretty new to debian, and I'm trying to set up a server.

I have created a user who can only access his folder `/home/username` (and its subdirectory).

Now I want to use that user for the webserver I set up, and I have given him access to `/var/www` but I can't see `/var/www` through sftp and I did a symbolic link like this:

```
root@server:/home/username# ln -s /var/www www
root@server:/home/username# cd www
root@server:/home/username/www# chown username:username *
```

Now, with filezilla, I can see www folder like this:

[image: Filezilla]

But when I try to open it, I get this:

[image: Open]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's likely the SFTP is being chrooted, so that the directory /var/www is not available to the user in the chroot jail.

Look in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and examine the sftp directives.  Do you see something like:

```
Match group sftp
  ChrootDirectory /home/%u
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

The sshd_config man page is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config).

Basically, once the user is in `/home/username` in SFTP, that directory becomes `/` and references outside of `/home/username` are not available.  In fact, a symlink like `ln -s /var/www /home/username/www` will look like you're trying to reach `/home/username/var/www` (i.e., `/home/username` is now `/` so any link that references `/var/www` must also be a subdirectory of `/home/username` in the context of the chroot).

As a solution, you can turn off the chroot (but this will have other security implications, mainly with SFTP users having full rein over your filesystem).  You can do a loop mount of /var/www into /home/username/www (something like `mount --bind /var/www /home/username/www` (check your documentation for `mount`) which should work as you'd expect under chroot).  You can also muck with the sshd_config file to exclude that one particular user from chroot (though, again, with security implications).

I would try the bind mount first.

Comment: +1 for the mount --bind trick!

Comment: If you want it to be persistent across reboots, edit your `/etc/fstab` with a line like `/home/username/www    /var/www    none    bind    0 0`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved unlinking the symlink I made and with

```
root@server:/home/username# mkdir www
root@server:/home/username# mount --bind /home/username/www /var/www
```

(even if I've lost everything was in /var/www, but I don't care)

thanks all!

Comment: You haven't lost anything.  Simply unmount and copy your files before you remount.

Comment: uuuhhh thank you! i had nothing but 1 file with a link, nothing important, but i couldn't figure out to recover it :D

Comment: however should be noted that links are hard saved into the fs, but mounts need to be executed at restarts either manually or using fstab